# My home monitoring camera sends me thousands of e-mails every day

Tags: digital-cameras, home-security, surveillance-cameras

I've got a Linksys Wireless Internet Monitoring Camera (WVC54GCA with the recent firmware), which I've setup at home. I configured it to send me 5 second short videos to my e-mail on any physical movements during my absence. Despite my effort to configure the best settings, I still get the thousands of e-mails every day (one every minute or more) with no movements on them, but only slight contrast changes.

Here are examples of three different videos:

[image: Video feed: Linksys Wireless Internet Monitoring Camera, WVC54GCA]
[image: Video feed: Linksys Wireless Internet Monitoring Camera, WVC54GCA]
[image: Video feed: Linksys Wireless Internet Monitoring Camera, WVC54GCA]

Is there anything that I can do about this problem? Or I should buy a better one?

To clarify, I want to receive the e-mails, but with valid physical movements on the attached videos.

---

Here are my configuration settings from /adm/image_fs.htm page:

[image: Linksys WVC54GCA Wireless Internet Monitoring Camera, image admin configuration page]

The White Balance options (if relevant) can be selected to: Auto, Indoor (Incandescent), Fluorescent (white light), Fluorescent (yellow light), Outdoor or Black & White.

Settings at /adm/event_fs.htm page:

[image: Linksys WVC54GCA, image admin configuration page, Motion Detection Settings, Trigger Motion Detection]

Comment: It would be great if you could also add Motion Detection Settings that you have right now.

Comment: I'd try un-ticking the *low light sensitivity* first. Might compromise motion detection at night though...

Comment: What did the manufacturer say, when you asked them?

Comment: I didn't ask, but most likely would send me the user guide.

Comment: "I still get the thousands of e-mails every day (one every minute or more) with no movements on them" Am so no paranormal jokes or puns?

Comment: @HenryWHHackv2.1.1 I've advanced and without camera I got hundreds e-mails per minute (hundred thousands per day), so not much difference for me with camera. I had to upgrade recently my mail from 100G to 1TB and improve my filters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally speaking you have to adjust the trigger for the motion detection. There's the sensitivity for the actual motion detection and that is as bravokeyl already says despite all technology most efficiently done by trial and error.

That might not work the same for all times of day due to low sun, clouds and other factors changing the lighting. Also cats. Motion detection and cats mix badly. Looking at the now provided options of your settings I'd start with deactivating the *low light sensitivity* box and check the results. At day and night. This might turn the camera useless at night, but that has to be tested with the actual device.

There is however another setting that might help you out that is listed in the handbook:

> **Interval** Enter the time in minutes that must pass
>   between motion detection events. Valid values are 0-5,
>   10, or 15. The default is 2. A value of 0 indicates no delay
>   between events.

[WVC54GCA User guide](http://downloads.linksys.com/downloads/userguide/1224639055972/WVC54GCA-EU_V10_UG_A-WEB.pdf)

It seems like that setting is set to zero if you get that many mails. Maybe revert it to default or even to five minutes. That should definitely reduce the amount of mails.

Comment: Correct, the _Interval_ between detecting the next motion is set to 0, but then if something real happens, then I won't see the thief again on the upcoming videos for X number of minutes. He would likely notice the camera and disconnect it, till I'll get another video of him:)

Comment: I've tested with _low light sensitivity_ disabled and also White Balance set to _Black & White_ and recorded a plain wall for half a day, not ideal, but the e-mails are significantly less frequent.

Answer (score 5):

My DLink camera also warns me about luminosity changes (clouds,...) but no too often. Take a look at your camera settings to search for a "threshold" value and reduce it.

Another quite heavy solution should be to upload pictures to a local FTP (or something else) server, watch for file modifications and send them less often via a program which handles a timer.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have the setup in question with me but I try to answer in general. Normally any sensor that detects changes in motion depends on the configuration that we set for **sensitivity, threshold**. I presume the camera in the question might have an option to set the sensivity threshold, exactly how much threshold to put is uncertain to say.

In my opinion, the threshold that you need can be found by trial and error method. May be adjust sensitivity to lower level and threshold to a higher level and check.